# How can I test Google Auth with Firebase Emulator in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, firebase-tools

I use Firebase Emulator to test Firestore, Cloud Functions, and Auth. I've been using Sign In with Email and Password. Now, I want to implement Google Auth. How can I test Google Auth using Firebase Emulator in Flutter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential)`
should work even in firebase emulator

`credential` should taken from `GoogleAuthProvider.credential()`

Comment: Not working for me , I get an `Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(sign_in_failed, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 10: , null, null)` exception message. Is there a step I missed?

Comment: you need to use emulator that contain google api

Comment: you are talking about the device emulator? I am using one with Google services enabled. Do I need to do anything more?

Comment: Not working for me too...
I build my application on release mode after that I install in on the emulator it work...

But on debug mode it not work